# Node.js and sqlite, SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range

Tags: node.js, sqlite, coffeescript

**See my answer below for a MWE!**

I know it sound stupid and the answer is probably right in front of me, but I can't figure out why I get this SQLITE_RANGE error, since my object looks like it has every properties needed.

```
    console.log "values " ,  values

    #   Recording in db
    console.assert values.login?
    console.assert values.password_sha?     
    console.assert values.email?
    console.assert values.token?
    values.password = null
    @db.run "INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, $login, $password_sha, $email, $token)", values, (err) ->
        console.error err if err?
```

Here is the output of my server

```
values  { login: 'ostream',
  email: 'ijw',
  password: 'justine',
  token: 'acppn99ngiafw29',
  password_sha: 'b1820c2ec34175954bdaa42038b48886b4c83f8d53f88b5315c415898855e4f8' }

{ [Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range] errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE' }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try specify columns `INSERT INTO user(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (...)` where `col..` is your column name . If first column is auto_increment skip it and do not set NULL

Comment: FTR here's the .schema of my table : 
    `CREATE TABLE user (id integer primary key, login text, password_sha text, email text, token text);`

Comment: lad2025: it seems to work yeah. Why can't I insert the values directly? The .schema seems to match.

Comment: Still I can't insert into my database. See my answer below

Answer (score 10):

Apparently what you need to do is make sure the keys in your `user` object are prefixed with `$`. Otherwise `sqlite3` won't recognise them as values for placeholders. Try:

```
sqlite3 = require 'sqlite3'
db = new sqlite3.Database('testfile.db');

user = 
    $name: 'hello'
    $password: 'jambon'

db.run 'insert into "user" (name, password) VALUES ($name, $password)', user, (err) ->
    console.log 'request executed : ', err
```

It's not very well documented, but looking at [the test cases](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/7322ea714b13451bab75d5232a1dd2a05fcb5052/test/named_params.test.js#L14-L49) you can see that there are other options, like prefixing them with `@` or `:`. In any case, your object has to match the placeholders including the prefix.

Comment: Also I found that if you have any extra properties in the object that don't map to keys in the query, then it gives the same `column index out of range` error

Answer (score 3):

You should always specify column list when you `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO "user"(login, password_sha, email, token)
VALUES ('ostream',
        'b1820c2ec34175954bdaa42038b48886b4c83f8d53f88b5315c415898855e4f8',
        'ijw', 'acppn99ngiafw29');

SELECT *
FROM "user"
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0002c/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that `user` is keyword and should be quoted with `"` or you can rename table to `users`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the number of parameters matches.
2. For all SQL commands make sure the name of parameters matches.

Notice that **$myValues** != **$myValue** in my example:

```
let sqlRequest = "INSERT into myTable (myValue) VALUES ($myValue)";
let sqlParams = { $myValues: "Wrong parameter name" };
this.common.run(sqlRequest, sqlParams);
```